# Insert from Select except specific column(s) in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, we need to do a quick Insert for an almost identical row with specific different value(s) that we specify. Identical to a Select for a similar value, except one or two columns. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into yourTable (col1, col2, col3)
select col1, col2, 'diffValue'
  from someTable
 where SomePK = SomeVal;
```